# How do I add a side text to my document

Tags: graphics, covers

The university where I study provide us with a docs template for our reports that is mandatory to use. I wanted to recreate it in Latex so it's easier to edit with formulas, tables and referencing but I'm finding the front page really hard to replicate. There is this text on side written: "Universidade Federal de Itajubá" that is sideways and I can't think of a way to add.

You can see how the template looks like here:

[image]

Any idea on how I can do that or tips to replicate that page?

This is what I have so far but I'm not being able to put the text in a box like it is on the template

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{GASS-WEB: a web server for identifying enzyme active sites based on genetic algorithms}
\author{João Pedro Areias de Moraes}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{republica.png}
\begin{center}
Universidade federal de Itajubá \\
\textit{Campus Itabira}
\end{center}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{path4742.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

\thetitle



\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide MWE

Comment: Sorry about that, there you go

Comment: I know right and we have to write with it. Anyway, I guess I will have to deal with it

Comment: I assume the lower framed box is not a graphics actually but something to fill in?

Comment: Yes, both of the frame boxes, the first one I need to put the title of my project and the second the information about me

Comment: @JoãoAreias: I think you need some nested `tabular` or `tabularx` environments here, with a  `\rotatebox` in a tabular cell  for the left vertical text

Comment: The easiest way: Use the existing `.doc` (?) template, fill in the titlepage content, expert the titlepage only and use `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and `\includepdf{mybeautifultitlepage.pdf}` ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You are soooo right.  That answer should get a hundred +1!

Comment: @Jan: Thanks ... every one of my answers gets a hundred of upvotes :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: But only 1 % or less is from me. :-(

Comment: @Jan: It was a joke actually ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an really odd solution.  It is a quick hack.  You have to polish a lot, to get those nifty fonts and shades (maybe TikZ could be a help, I have no idea!).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\def\@instituto{}
\def\@titulo{}
\def\@aluno{}
\def\@matricula{}
\def\@curso{}
\def\@orientador{}
\def\@fase{}
\def\@vigencia{}
\newcommand{\instituto}[1]{\def\@instituto{#1}}
\newcommand{\titulo}[1]{\def\@titulo{#1}}
\newcommand{\aluno}[1]{\def\@aluno{#1}}
\newcommand{\matricula}[1]{\def\@matricula{#1}}
\newcommand{\curso}[1]{\def\@curso{#1}}
\newcommand{\orientador}[1]{\def\@orientador{#1}}
\newcommand{\fase}[1]{\def\@fase{#1}}
\newcommand{\vigencial}[1]{\def\@vigencial{#1}}

% Define the unreadable color in the lower box
\definecolor{nonexistent}{RGB}{222,222,222}


\newcommand{\maketitulo}{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5mm}
  % begin a new page
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
  % insert the Logo
  \noindent%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{ulogo}%
  % insert the instituto name
  \raisebox{0.8cm}{\Large\textbf{(\textcolor{red}{\@instituto})}}\\[2ex]%
  % insert the rotated text
  \parbox[b][0.6\textheight][t]{2cm}{%
    \centering%
    \rotatebox{90}{\huge%
      \bfseries{Universidade Federal de Itajub\'a}}}%
  \hfill%
  \parbox[b][0.6\textheight][t]{0.8\textwidth}{%
%  \parbox{0.7\textwidth}{%
    \centering%
    \fbox{%
      \parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\centering\LARGE\scshape{\@titulo}}}\\%
    \vspace{3cm}%
    EDITE ESTA LINHA LOREM IPSUM DOLORET\\%
    \vspace{0.8cm}%
    REALTARIO PARCIVAL (OUFINAL)\\%
    UNIFEI\\%
    (lorem ipsum dolores amet)\\%
    \vspace{1cm}
    \fbox{%
      \parbox{0.7\textwidth}{\flushleft\textcolor{nonexistent}{%
        Aluno: \@aluno\\%
        Matricula: \@matricula\\%
        Curso: \@curso\\%
        Orientador:\ \@orientador\\[3ex]%
        Fase/Periodo: \@fase\\[3ex]%
        Vigencial: \@vigencial}}}
  }
}    

\titulo{My Title}
\instituto{Some Other Institute}
\vigencial{I Have No Idea}
\fase{The Phase Of The Moon}
\orientador{AC/DC}
\curso{Not Getting Blinded By This}

\begin{document}
\maketitulo
\end{document}
```

This is the outcome (You have been warned, it is awkward!)

[image]

Comment: Mr. Spock would say `Fascinating` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As to the box around the title:

```
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}
\fbox{\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\centering Titulo de Projecto}}
```

Fiddle with the fboxrule, to adapt it to the given rule width.

Maybe you want to make a command from it:

```
\newcommand{\titlebox}[1]{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}%
  \centering%
  \fbox{%
    \scshape{}\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\centering\LARGE\scshape{#1}}}}
```

In total:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}

\newcommand{\titlebox}[1]{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}%
  \centering%
  \fbox{%
    \scshape{}\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\centering\LARGE\scshape{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
% This is the titlebox
\titlebox{Titulo de Projecto}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the package `graphicx` and follow the below code:

```
\rotatebox{90}{Universidade Federal de Itajub\'a}
```

[image]

Comment: But then how can I put the tables on the side with the text on it like the text in "Titulo do projeto"?